# In css code a:active is not working

Tags: css, menu, background, navigation, hover

I am using CSS code like this

```
.top_nav ul li a{ 
  color: #444; background: #111;
}
.top_nav ul li a:hover{
  color: #fff; background: #555;
}
.top_nav ul li a:active{
  color: #111; background: #fff;
}
```

But the problem is this when any page is active, on **navigation menu** that link's background not change. Background of that link is same as other's.

Comment: could you offer some more code or a link?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for focusing an active link in your menu with different color. Mind that `a:active` is not intended for that purpose.

A link only takes up the `a:active` state when it is clicked, so you only see the change for a few seconds. You should look for a different way for getting it done, like adding a  new css class for the selected menu item from your server side script.

Comment: You see active state for as long as you hold down mouse button after click.

Comment: Right. I pointed out in the usual context where one just clicks a button not hold it down.

Answer (score 1):

The active is only applied when you click on it. Do it like this:

```
<li><a href="" class="active">Link</a></li>
```

And then style it

```
top_nav ul li a.active {
   color: #111;
   background: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The a:active selector refers to active state of a link, not your active page.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

You will have to set some "active page" class to your menu item for the page you are currently viewing and refer to that in yor CSS.

If you have static HTML pages, you can add a class to your navigation items representing the current active page:

```
<li class="current">...</li>
```

and then change your css to:

```
.top_nav ul li.current a {
  color: #111; background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i am doing this in simple html and css, means using on static page not dynamic

Comment: Then what is your "active page"?
If you have multiple static pages, then add in your navigation list items for example: `<li class="active">..</li>` and change your css to `.top_nav ul li.active a { ...`

Comment: Removed my comment all together, since you said the same thing. @FarazKhan, as a side note, here's a pretty easy way of doing the same thing with php http://www.alistapart.com/articles/keepingcurrent/

Comment: Updated my original answer with the new information from these comments.